# how to make seperate UI in android mobile device and tablet

Tags: android

i always working in android mobile devices. i want to run my projects in android tablet devices.

so my questions are

1. do i have to face any compatible issue?
2. will same project run with different view in different target such as one for tablet one for mobile device?
   in example can it set in android mainfest.xml so it can choose different view in different device

and please help about how to solve this, with some help link

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the android developer site on this?

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It covers the issue in detail.

Comment: thank u, i want a simple view for mobile device and tabbed view in android tablet device, can i use same project to do this, or i need to create different projects

Comment: You can probably use one project for that. You might want to look into Fragments, which were designed to represent pieces of the UI, and so split up into multiple screens for mobile, or one screen on a tablet http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html