# Android Mobile And Tablet Same Apk

Tags: android

i am android newbie my client requirement is that he want same apk for mobile and tablet when that app serach on mobile than show mobile compatible apk and if search by table than show tablet compatible  apk on google play i would like to know that is possible or not if yes than how.

How i build one (Same) Apk for Tablet and Mobile.

Comment: it s possible you can make with layout modification and manifest options

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make seperate UI in android mobile device and tablet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368951/how-to-make-seperate-ui-in-android-mobile-device-and-tablet)

Comment: Have you tried google *at all*?

Answer (score 5):

Add these lines to manifest file

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true"]
                />
```

please refer this link:

[Distributing to Specific Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

[android screen compatible mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

please read following documentation for supporting multiple screens

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

from google docs

To disable this version of screen compatibility mode, you simply need to set android:minSdkVersion or android:targetSdkVersion to "4" or higher, or set android:resizeable to "true".

use following for adding multiple screen support :

you should include the element in your manifest file like shown on following link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

correct me if im wrong but I think the apk for mobile can be used to install the app in tablet.your problem would be in the ui coz mobile has smaller screen than tablet